# How can I set a constant in autoconf checking for a program?

Tags: constants, autotools, autoconf

I am using autotools and I have a configure.ac script that says this:

```
AC_CHECK_PROG(RASPIVID, raspivid, yes)
```

However, the generated config.h file does not show a RASPIVID constant. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AC_CHECK_PROG` macro does not do anything with config.h by itself. From [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Generic-Programs.html#Generic-Programs):

> **AC_CHECK_PROG** (*variable*, *prog-to-check-for*, *value-if-found*, [*value-if-not-found*], [*path* = '$PATH'], [*reject*])
>
> Check whether program *prog-to-check-for* exists in path. If it is found, set *variable* to *value-if-found*, otherwise to *value-if-not-found*, if given. Always pass over *reject* (an absolute file name) even if it is the first found in the search path; in that case, set *variable* using the absolute file name of the *prog-to-check-for* found that is not *reject*. If *variable* was already set, do nothing. Calls **AC_SUBST** for *variable*. The result of this test can be overridden by setting the *variable* variable or the cache variable ac_cv_prog_*variable*.

So `AC_CHECK_PROG(RASPIVID, raspivid, yes)` will check whether `raspivid` exists. If it does, it will set the shell variable `RASPIVID` to the value `yes`, so you could perform a test after the `AC_CHECK_PROG` invocation such as:

```
AC_CHECK_PROG([RASPIVID], [raspivid], [yes])
AS_IF([test "x$RASPIVID" = xyes],
    [AC_DEFINE([HAVE_RASPIVID], [1], [raspivid is available.])])
```

[`AC_SUBST`](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Setting-Output-Variables.html#Setting-Output-Variables) will be called already as mentioned in the documentation, so you can use `$(RASPIVID)` in a makefile or whatever the output file(s) may be.